# Can I convert individual fields of a 'mysql_query' to arrays?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Likely a remedial question, but in all my days as a PHP user I have yet to encounter an answer.  Basically, is there any way to grab a single field of a "mysql_query" as an array?  For instance say I have the following:

```
$query = "Select id,first_name,last_name FROM people";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Is there any way to grab each (id, first_name, last_name) as individual arrays without iterating through the recordset?  Can I say something like:

```
$ids = field_to_array($result['id']);
$first_names = field_to_array($result['first_name']);
$last_names = field_to_array($result['last_name']);
```

As I said, in the past I've always simply built the arrays as needed, but an existing method would be handy.

Comment: You mean, to turn around the grid so that `$result['id']` contains, say, the 50 id's from the result set?

Comment: You want the whole column as an array?

Comment: WITHOUT iterating through result set?  If you don't hit each row returned how can you populate any array, much less a transposed one?

Comment: @Pekka, McKay:   Yes, that is exactly what I'm trying to do.  As I said, I've been simply iterating through the recordset.  I was hoping PHP had a native method to do such a thing.

Comment: @Xepoch:  Yes, of course *some* method has to do it, I was simply curious as to whether PHP had a native mechanism.  That's all.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql doesn't have that as a native function. you could always write your own..

```
function mysql_convert_cols($dataset) {
    foreach ($dataset as $row => $values) {
        foreach ($values as $column => $value) {
            $return[$$column][$row] = $value;
        }
    }
    return($return);
}

$resultConverted = mysql_convert_cols($result);
$id=$resultConverted['id'];
$firstName=$resultConverted['firstName'];
```

Comment: Yup, that's basically what I've been doing.  The only difference, however, I've only been concerned with one field at a time, and as such have set the function to process only a single field (as opposed to getting them all at once).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why do you need this , but you can do it like this :

```
$resultArray = array();  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
       $resultArray[] = array(
          "id" =>  $row['id'],
          "firstName"=>$row['first_name'],
          "lastName"=>$row['last_name']
      );
    }
```

Check if values are in :

```
print_r($resultArray);
```

Then you can foreach or to do the for loop on values.